# How to interrupt the published flowable

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

How can I interrupt a long-term task?

```
public Flowable<Integer> simple(int number) {
    Flowable<Integer> flowable = Flowable.create(emitter -> {
        for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                throw e;
            }
            emitter.onNext(i);
        }
        emitter.onComplete();
    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
    flowable = flowable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
    return flowable.publish().autoConnect();
}
```

The task is continued after I call the dispose method when the flowable was made published. So I want to catch an interrupted exception.

```
Flowable<Integer> f = simple(100);
Disposable d = f.subscribe(number -> System.out.println(number));
Thread.sleep(500);
d.dispose();
```

Also it has the same behavior with replay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the thread you're executing on and register the disposable to interrupt the thread.

```
Flowable<Integer> flowable = Flowable.create(emitter -> {
    Thread myThread = Thread.currentThread();
    emitter.setCancellable(() -> myThread.interrupt());

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; ++i) {
        if (Thread.interrupted()) {
            // Handle interrupt happening while Thread.sleep
            //  was not executing here.
        }
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw e;
        }
        emitter.onNext(i);
    }
    emitter.onComplete();
}, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
```

Comment: Does It work when sleep is too long (Thread.sleep(1000000);) or there is a blocking IO operation?

Comment: In theory it should work as long as its an operation listed in `Thread.interrupt()`.